# Refreshing JTable after query is executed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, refresh

I am working on my Java MySql project. I am showing workers in Kitchen Department meals that they need to prepare for guests. When my app starts it fetches unprepared meals from database and displays them in JTable. After they have done it, they check field "done" in table and they press confirm button. Now I want that my table is refreshed when they click order button and that table shows only meals that they need to prepare. I don't have problems with that, I just execute query and I can get unprepared meals from database. My problem is that I don't know how to refresh table. In code I have wrote comment where I think that JTable needs to be refreshed. I am using AbstractTableModel.

Picture of my JTable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TksPx.jpg

Here is my TableModel class:

```
public class KitchenTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private ArrayList<WrapperKitchen> hrana;

public KitchenTableModel(ArrayList<WrapperKitchen> hrana2) {
    this.hrana = hrana2;

}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 8;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return hrana.size();
}

public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex) {
    case 0:return "Order number";
    case 1:return "Room";
    case 2:return "Category";
    case 3:return "Meal";
    case 4:return "Quantity";
    case 5:return "Note";
    case 6:return "Order time";
    case 7:return "Done";
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WrapperKitchen jelo = hrana.get(rowIndex);
    switch (columnIndex) {
    case 0:return jelo.getIdUslugaHrana();
    case 1:return jelo.getBrojSobe();
    case 2:return jelo.getNazivKategorija();
    case 3:return jelo.getNazivHrane();
    case 4:return jelo.getKolicina();
    case 5:return jelo.getNapomena();
    case 6:return jelo.getDatumVrijeme();
    case 7:return jelo.getIzvrseno();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    if (columnIndex == 7)
        return Boolean.class;
    return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
    return (colIndex == 7);
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object inValue, int inRow, int inCol) {
    if(inRow < 0 || inCol < 0 || inRow >= getRowCount() )
        return;

    WrapperKitchen jelo= hrana.get(inRow);
        switch (inCol) {
            case 0:jelo.setIdUslugaHrana((int)inValue);break;
            case 1:jelo.setBrojSobe((int)inValue);break;
            case 2:jelo.setNazivKategorija((String)inValue);break;
            case 3:jelo.setNazivHrane((String)inValue);break;
            case 4:jelo.setKolicina((int)inValue);break;
            case 5:jelo.setNapomena((String)inValue);break;
            case 6:jelo.setDatumVrijeme((Date)inValue);break;
            case 7:jelo.setIzvrseno((boolean)inValue);break;
            default: throw new RuntimeException("something bad happen incorrect column " + inCol);
        }
        fireTableCellUpdated(inRow, inCol);

    }
```

}

Here is code of my JButton ActionListener with commented line:

```
    ActionListener a1 = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        IzvrseneNarudzbe.clear();
        boolean izvrseno;
        int id;
        for(int red=0;red<KuhinjaListaJela.size();red++){
            Object obj = Tablica.getModel().getValueAt(red, 7);
            izvrseno=(boolean)obj;
            if(izvrseno==true)
            {
                Object obj2 = Tablica.getModel().getValueAt(red, 0);
                id=(int)obj2;
                IzvrseneNarudzbe.add(id);
            }
        }
        izvrsiQuery();
        //IN THIS LINE I NEED TO REFRESH MY JTABLE

    }

    void izvrsiQuery(){
        for(int i=0;i<IzvrseneNarudzbe.size();i++){
            String SqlQuery="UPDATE `room_service`.`usluga_hrana` SET `izvrseno` = '" + 1 +"' WHERE `usluga_hrana`.`id_usluga_hrana` ="+IzvrseneNarudzbe.get(i);
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager
                        .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
                                + "localhost:3306/room_service",
                                "root", "");
                Statement Stat = (Statement) con.createStatement();
                int Rez = Stat.executeUpdate(SqlQuery);

                Stat.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                System.out.println(e2);
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your button's `ActionListener`, you should invoke `setValueAt()` to update your `TableModel` with the results of your query. The model will `fireTableCellUpdated()` to notify the table to update itself.